# Xorg - laptop - very poor gaming performance, broken external display connectivity

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, games, nvidia-optimus

Firstly, I appologise if this has been answered already (I could not find anything on this topic) or if it is something simple, I am not very adept at Linux.

I need help - I am using a laptop with an intel iGPU and nvidia dGPU (MSI GF65). I recently switched from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 by doing a fresh install. When I try to run a game on the Nvidia GPU using the context menu "Launch using Discrete Graphics card" or
`__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia %some_game%`
I notice a problem - terrible performance with GPU utilization being very low and one CPU core maxed out, while the others are almost idle. Running the same apps on the iGPU produces no such issue.

Another problem I am noticing is that external displays do not work. From what I know, the laptop monitor is connected to the iGPU, while the HDMI output of the laptop is connected to the dGPU, meaning its something to do with Nvidia.

These problems appears only with Xorg, not Wayland desktop environments. By not touching anything and simply switching to Wayland, external displays work and gaming on the Nvidia GPU works as intended. With Ubuntu 20.04 I had no such problems. I do have the CUDA toolkit installed for use with Tensorflow, but without its driver (works with the distribution drivers). I also had it installed with Ubuntu 20.04, where I did not have these issues.

---

I've tried the following in Xorg:

1. Different drivers (525, 530, 535, 545)
2. Purging all Nvidia drivers and installing the recommended one (535)
3. Switching prime profiles between "on-demand" and "nvidia" yields no change in behavior, behaves as if its "on-demand".
4. Generating an Xorg config file from Nvidia prevents all Xorg desktop environments from being selectable. I am able to use only Wayland. Using wayland in this way forces all rendering to be done on the Nvidia GPU, which is terrible for battery efficiency.
5. Generating Xorg config file with "Xorg -configure" results in error: "Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices"
6. Using a different desktop environment (Cinnamon) - same problems.

---

**EDIT:**
Here is the output of: *xrandr --listproviders*

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x44 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x1fe cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

Comment: When running xorg, please run xrandr --listproviders and include the output in your original posting.  I have seen the source/sink get reversed for some unknown reason sometimes, and some things simply wont run, so I'd think  bad performance is possible too.  e.g. CUDA samples won't run when source/sink reversed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am not too sure what it means, but I would guess sink is supposed to be the GPU connected to a display and source is the GPU, running a game?

Comment: The providers look reversed.  No idea why, mine seem random, sometimes one way, sometimes the other. You can switch them with env variables: __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <progtorun>

Comment: Oh, those commands are the ones I use for running games on the Nvidia GPU. Using them or the context menu "Launch using Discrete Graphics card" results in the mentioned problem in Xorg, but not in Wayland.